# Missing ) after For-loop. Not idea what's wrong.

Tags: javascript, xml-parsing

I'm attempting to run this script to parse an XML document.  When I validate the js I get a missing  ) after for-loop. I'm new to programming and not sure where I've gone wrong.  I've posted the entire js file at the end.  Thanks!

```
var meds = [];
for (var i = docMedActivities.size(); i--; i &gt;= 0) {
    var activity = docMedActivities.get(i);
    var material = activity.getConsumable().getManufacturedProduct().getManufacturedMaterial();

meds.push({ 
    name: String(material.getName().getText()),
    displayName: String(material.getCode().getDisplayName()),
    ndc: String(material.getCode().getTranslations().get(0).getCode()),
    doseQty: String(activity.getDoseQuantity().getValue()),
    effectiveDateTime: String(activity.getEffectiveTimes().get(0).getLow().getValue()), // 20120502000000+0000
    code: String(material.getCode().getCode())
});
}
```

Entire js file below :

```
// Load the CCD Document
var doc = org.openhealthtools.mdht.uml.cda.util.CDAUtil.load(new java.io.ByteArrayInputStream(messageObject.getRawData().getBytes("UTF-8")));

// Get CCD Document Sections to be parsed
var docPatientRole = doc.getRecordTargets().get(0).getPatientRole();
var docPatient = docPatientRole.getPatient();
var docPatientName = docPatient.getNames().get(0);
var docPatientAddress = docPatientRole.getAddrs().get(0);
var docMedSection = doc.getMedicationsSection();
var docMedActivities = docMedSection.getMedicationActivities();

// Patient Identity
var patient = {
firstName:  String(docPatientName.getGivens().get(0).getText()),
lastName: String(docPatientName.getFamilies().get(0).getText()),
genderCode: String(docPatient.getAdministrativeGenderCode().getCode()),
dateOfBirth: String(docPatient.getBirthTime().getValue()) // YYYYMMDD
};

// Patient Address
var address = {
addressCity: String(docPatientAddress.getCities().get(0).getText()),
addressState: String(docPatientAddress.getStates().get(0).getText()),
addressPostalCode: String(docPatientAddress.getPostalCodes().get(0).getText())
};

// Patient Medication Activities
var meds = [];
for (var i = docMedActivities.size(); i--; i &gt;= 0) {
var activity = docMedActivities.get(i);
var material =   activity.getConsumable().getManufacturedProduct().getManufacturedMaterial();

meds.push({
    name: String(material.getName().getText()),
    displayName: String(material.getCode().getDisplayName()),
    ndc: String(material.getCode().getTranslations().get(0).getCode()),
    doseQty: String(activity.getDoseQuantity().getValue()),
    effectiveDateTime: String(activity.getEffectiveTimes().get(0).getLow().getValue()), // 20120502000000+0000
    code: String(material.getCode().getCode())
});
}

// Populate Channel Map, use JSON so logs are readable
channelMap.put(&apos;patient&apos;, JSON.stringify(patient, null, 2));
channelMap.put(&apos;address&apos;, JSON.stringify(address, null, 2));
channelMap.put(&apos;meds&apos;, JSON.stringify(meds, null, 2));</script>
      <type>JavaScript</type>
      <data class="map">
        <entry>
          <string>Script</string>
          <string>// Load the CCD Document
var doc = org.openhealthtools.mdht.uml.cda.util.CDAUtil.load(new    java.io.ByteArrayInputStream(messageObject.getRawData().getBytes(&quot;UTF-8&quot;)));

// Get CCD Document Sections to be parsed
var docPatientRole = doc.getRecordTargets().get(0).getPatientRole();
var docPatient = docPatientRole.getPatient();
var docPatientName = docPatient.getNames().get(0);
var docPatientAddress = docPatientRole.getAddrs().get(0);
var docMedSection = doc.getMedicationsSection();
var docMedActivities = docMedSection.getMedicationActivities();

// Patient Identity
var patient = {
firstName:  String(docPatientName.getGivens().get(0).getText()),
lastName: String(docPatientName.getFamilies().get(0).getText()),
genderCode: String(docPatient.getAdministrativeGenderCode().getCode()),
dateOfBirth: String(docPatient.getBirthTime().getValue()) // YYYYMMDD
};

// Patient Address
var address = {
addressCity: String(docPatientAddress.getCities().get(0).getText()),
addressState: String(docPatientAddress.getStates().get(0).getText()),
addressPostalCode: String(docPatientAddress.getPostalCodes().get(0).getText())
};

// Patient Medication Activities
var meds = [];
for (var i = docMedActivities.size(); i--; i &gt;= 0) {
var activity = docMedActivities.get(i);
var material =   activity.getConsumable().getManufacturedProduct().getManufacturedMaterial();

meds.push({
    name: String(material.getName().getText()),
    displayName: String(material.getCode().getDisplayName()),
    ndc: String(material.getCode().getTranslations().get(0).getCode()),
    doseQty: String(activity.getDoseQuantity().getValue()),
    effectiveDateTime: String(activity.getEffectiveTimes().get(0).getLow().getValue()), // 20120502000000+0000
    code: String(material.getCode().getCode())
});
}

// Populate Channel Map, use JSON so logs are readable
channelMap.put(&apos;patient&apos;, JSON.stringify(patient, null, 2));
channelMap.put(&apos;address&apos;, JSON.stringify(address, null, 2));
channelMap.put(&apos;meds&apos;, JSON.stringify(meds, null, 2));
```

Comment: `for (var i = docMedActivities.size(); i--; i &gt;= 0) {` .... `i &gt;= 0` ... ?

Comment: `org.openhealthtools.mdht.uml.cda.util.CDAUtil.load(new java.io.ByteArrayInputStream(messageObject.getRawData().getBytes("UTF-8")));` - is this really JavaScript?

Comment: @Bergi I guess it could be, but it looks incredibly unlikely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside a JS file, you need to write `>=` rather than `&gt;=`; the latter only makes sense when the JS is embedded inside (X)HTML PCDATA.

(The reason for the strange wording of the error-message is that the validator interprets `gt` as an identifier, and `i & gt` as an expression using [the bitwise-AND operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators). So when it sees the semicolon, it thinks the `for`-loop header should be over.)

---

**Edited to add:** Also, while your `for`-loop will work after you make this change, that's due only to a weird series of quirks and coincidences. This:

```
for (var i = docMedActivities.size(); i--; i >= 0) {
    ...
}
```

means this:

```
var i = docMedActivities.size();
while (i--) {      // note the post-increment: i-- evaluates to i's old value
    ...
    i >= 0;        // note that this expression has no side-effects
}
```

which is equivalent to this:

```
var i = docMedActivities.size();
while (i != 0) {
    i--;
    ...
}
i--;
```

which happens to do what you want. So your code happens to work correctly, but not for the reason that it *looks* like it does, and any minor future change will break it in horribly confusing ways.

What you really want to write is:

```
for (var i = docMedActivities.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    ...
}
```

(with `i >= 0` coming *before* `i--`, and with a `- 1` in the initialization expression).

Comment: Thanks so much for the quick reply!  This was exactly the problem.

Comment: Also `i--` should be after `i>=0`.

Comment: @jsizemore5665: You're welcome! By the way, I've updated my answer with a note about something else that you'll want to fix.

Comment: @Derek: Actually, it's a lot more complicated than that; I've updated my answer to explain. Thanks for mentioning it.

Comment: @ruakh - Thanks for the great explanation! Might do this in the future to shorten up my code: `for(var i=0;--i;){}`

Answer (score 1):

Inside a script, you don't need to escape HTML entities. The JS parser detects 3 semicolons in your for-statement, which is one too much to be valid - a closing parenthesis would be expected.

Also, you've swapped the condition with the update code. Change it to

```
for (var i = docMedActivities.size(); i>=0; i--)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with this part of your loop: `i &gt;= 0`

After the third comma the for statement normally ends which is why a closing parenthesis is expected/required. Change the `&gt;` to `>`. The `&gt;` means 'greater than', suggesting you copied this code in from somewhere but that it may need changing elsewhere.

Also I'm pretty sure the ordering of your for-statement should be:

```
for (var i = docMedActivities.size(); i >= 0; i--) {
```

Note that the `i--` should be the third part of the statement and the 'greater than' part should be second. Also the comma after the final part is not required.

As you're new to coding, I'd suggest taking a look at [this page on for-loops](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp) at least. But having a look around some introductions to JavaScript in general would be a good idea.

Hope this helps.